# github pages images not showing

Tags: angularjs, github

My images won't show up on an Angular 2 app on Github Pages. I could see the images during the app's development, but now the relative link returns the error: `Failed to Load Resource` on inspection.

The image link from development looks like this:

**/assets/images/juno.gif**

I tried copying the path from repo, but the image still doesn't show

**mybiography/src/assets/images/juno.gif**

I also tried copying the github link to the image file, but my Angular CLI service redirects me back to the application's home page.

**https://github.com/st4rgut22/mybiography/blob/master/src/assets/images/juno.gif**

Please advise what I should do, here's the link to the page where the images fail to show upon dropdown selection: https://st4rgut22.github.io/mybiography/work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using relative path just start src path with `./`

Change `src="/assets/images/rot.gif"` to `src="./assets/images/rot.gif"`

**N.B.** `./` denotes the current location